# How can I determine Time and Space Complexity of the below program?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

I just wrote a code regarding array rotation while studying for Data Structure. I needed to know how I can improve below program by measuring time and space complexity.

Program for array rotation.
Rotation of the array by 2 will make array

1,2,3,4
Input

3,4,1,2
Output

```
  public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arrayCount = 0;
            int rotate = 2;
        int []answer = new int[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                answer[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            arrayCount = answer.Count();
            ArrayRotation.displayRotatedArray(answer, rotate, arrayCount);
            ArrayRotation.printArray(answer, arrayCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

 public static class ArrayRotation
    {
        public static void displayRotatedArray(int []temp, int rotate, int count)
        {

           int c = rotate;
            int d = rotate;
            int[] firstOccurenceArray = new int[rotate];

                for (int g = 0; g < rotate; g++)
                {
                    int num = g;
                    firstOccurenceArray[g] = temp[g];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length - c; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = temp[rotate];
                    rotate++;
                }
            for (int k = 1; k < d + 1; k++)
            {
                temp[count - k] = firstOccurenceArray[c - 1];
                c--;
            }
        }
        /* utility function to print an array */
       public static void printArray(int[] temp, int size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                Console.Write( temp[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity is calculated: by what factor number of operations changes with respect to the change in size of input params.

For this example operation are changing as mentioned:

(2) + 2*rotate + 2* temp.Length + 2 * rotate

For max it can be 2 + (6 * temp.Length)
so time complexity is O(n).

Space complexity: O(rotate) which can be max to O(n)

You can optimize this problem in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity by in-place swapping(Juggling Algorithm) the array values.

**REF:**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity : O(n) where n = length of array (since there is no nested for loops)

Space Complexity : O(2) i.e. O(1)  (since size of this array firstOccurenceArray is constant i.e. 2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I change the constant value to more than 2 then what will happen?

Comment: Then, if(rotate>arrayCount) TimeComplexity = O(rotate)   else TimeComplexity=O(arrayCount)       And SpaceComplexity = O(rotate) in all cases  according to your code.

Comment: You can improve you time complexity and space complexity of your code if you do this `rotate=rotate%arrayCount`